# "The range cannot be deleted" when adding a table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a function to create a table in my Word document.

Running first `Main` in WordManager assigns `objWord` and `objDoc`. Running `FnAddTableToWordDocument` in WordFormating works on the first run but fails every time on the second run.

The error I get is the following:

> Run-time error 6028
>   The range cannot be deleted

On line:

```
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns
```

Two Modules:

Module #1 - WordManager:

```
Module WordManager    
Public objWord As Word.Application
Public objDoc As Word.Document

Sub Main() ' This is to be replaced by a call from the actual CA tool.
    Call initWordManager("[string path]", "test2.doc")
End Sub

Sub initWordManager(Path, Name)
    sFilePath = Path
    sFileName = Name

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True

    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
End Sub
```

Module #2 - WordFormating:

```
Function FnAddTableToWordDocument()

   Dim intNoOfRows

   Dim intNoOfColumns

   Dim objRange

   Dim objTable

 intNoOfRows = 5

 intNoOfColumns = 3


  objWord.Visible = True

  Set objRange = objDoc.Range

  objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns

  Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)

    objTable.Borders.Enable = True

  For i = 1 To intNoOfRows

     For j = 1 To intNoOfColumns

 objTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Text = "Sumit_" & i & j

     Next

  Next

End Function
```

Comment: That's probably documented on MSDN, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a more specific range solved the issue.

Set objRange = objDoc.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)

Does not give multiple tables but at least it does not cause an error.